# Looping rest api

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

I've REST API which exposes the JSON with a link to the next page and data as shown below:

```
{
 "nextPageLink" : "rest_api_url_to_next_page"
 "myData" : [ {
   "key" : {
      "d1" : "d1_value",
      "d2" : "d2_value"
    },
    "productData" : {
       "d3" : "d3_value",
       "d4" : "d4_value"
    }
    "d5" : "d5_value",
    "d6" : "d6_value"
}
```

There are around 1000s of pages with `nextPageLink`. On the last page, its empty. Can you please guide me how to design this in java. Also, I've such 10 more different REST APIs to handle.

My approach:

1. Create 2 pojos, one for key (keyPojo) and another for rest of the data(restDataPojo). Create a map with key as keyPojo and value as restDataPojo.
2. Create a pojo which has all the values, and dump data in the list of type pojo.

Is there any better approach to store such data? is this approach efficient enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'standard' solution to this sort of problem recommended by the [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](https://amzn.to/327rTgK) is to have an array of links tagged by a *relationship type* (typically called `rel`).

A typical 'page' would look like this:

```
{
    "links": [{
            "rel": "previous",
            "href": "http://example.com/pages/41"
        },
        {
            "rel": "next",
            "href": "http://example.com/pages/43"
        }
    ],
    "otherAttributes": "go here"
}
```

On the first page, you omit the `previous` link:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "next",
            "href": "http://example.com/pages/43"
        }
    ],
    "otherAttributes": "go here"
}
```

and on the last page, you omit the `next` link:

```
{
    "links": [{
            "rel": "previous",
            "href": "http://example.com/pages/41"
        }
    ],
    "otherAttributes": "go here"
}
```

Since `links` is an array, you can back all three cases with the same underlying DTO.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the approach. This was really helpful.